# bootstrap div is not resizing incrementally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Frontend is not my speciality, but need to tweak a bootstrap based website. Have been manipulating the heights of a certain div which is defined like this:

html:

```
<div class="cover-container d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
```

css:

```
.cover-container {
  max-width: 42em;
}
```

Yes, changing the `max-width` in the css has worked to reshape the div as I need it but lowering the `h-100` is having an unusual effect. It makes an enormous jump in height for example if I even change `h-100` to `h-99` - doubling it's height. Any ideas what is going on and how to make it move incrementally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because bootstrap doesn't support the `h-99` class and thus ignores it. When you write that, it's the same as not writing any `h-**` attribute.
Bootstrap only supports 25%, 50%, 75% and 100% [source](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/).
If you want to change the size to another value, you'll need to create your own size class. Bootstrap's `h-100` class is the same as:

```
.h-100 {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you wanted to implement a h-99 class, you'd simply need:

```
.h-99 {
  height: 99% !important;
}
```

If you've already done that but it didn't work (and that's why you resorted to using `max-width` instead, which is what I suppose happened), make sure that your custom width property isn't being overwritten by another. Add your class at the end of the `class=""` tag or add an `!important` tag at the end of the css width attribute you wish to apply. I can't really recommend using the `!important` tag because it can become a pain to overwrite if you reuse your classes, so avoid it whenever possible (though there's no shame in using it, BStrap uses it anyways).

---

Edit: On a side note, remember that if you specify `height: 25%;` and it still doesn't occupy 25% of the parent, you might need to add `position:relative;` to the parent itself. If the parent's `position` attribute isn't specified (the value doesn't matter for this), its client's percentage won't be relative to it but rather some other parent down the line.

---

If you want the element to take 25% of the viewport, use CSS viewport units `height: 25vh;` (vh=viewport-height).

Comment: _relative to its parent_ possibly explains some of what was observing

Comment: @cardamom True. Just added a reminder to my answer just in case it helps.